# Help with algorithm to find optimal route between various routes, where order matters

Tags: algorithms, path-finding

This seems to be a variation on the Travelling Salesman problem, and I started (as 
 far as some reading at least) going down that route to solve it, but the ordering restrictions are confusing me a bit.

- I have a map with an arbitrary number of destinations on it.
- An agent is given a set of trade routes.
- Each individual route must be processed in order, but all routes can be intermingled.

For example:

- I start at `S0`.
- I have a route `Alpha` that needs to visit `A1`, `A2` and `A3`.
- I have a route `Beta` that needs to visit `B4`, `B5` and `B6`.

A valid option would be to simply join the routes together:

`S0` -> `A1` -> `A2` -> `A3` -> `B4` -> `B5` -> `B6`

But perhaps parts of *Beta* are actually near the beginning parts of *Alpha*, so it would be better to go:

`S0` -> `A1` -> `B4` -> `B5` -> `A2` -> `A3` -> `B6`

Is there a way to calculate an optimal (or "probably quite optimal") route between these nodes, without calculating every distance between every possible pair of nodes? Alternatively I could construct a graph of every possible journey, but that also seems like it could get problematic.

Comment: To me it seems like normal traveling salesman, with additional constraint, that some nodes must be visited in specific order.

Answer (score 3):

The striking thing about this problem is that every time there are only two choices, the next A or the next B. That means I could encode the route as AAABBB. Which in that case means choose all the A's then all the B's.

That makes exploring every possible journey simple. Just [permute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) that string. If you're reluctant to calculate all of those you could run the greedy algorithm and just always choose which ever is shorter, A or B, at each step. It can't guarantee to be optimal but it is likely to be reasonable.

Comment: Well, you can easily apply Dijkstra's algorithm. Put A and B in a priority queue by their length so far. Then pick the shortest, add A and B to it and put those in the queue. When the first element is complete, you have the solution.

Comment: I've gone for a nearest-neighbour algorithm to start with, as you suggested in your second paragraph. I'll have to see anything more precise or fancy is needed.